# Android ListItem Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a ListItem that is used in my REST based application to populate a ListView. The preview in Android studio looks correct however the application itself is displayed oddly. I've messed around with match_parent as well as wrap_content for the TextViews in the provided layout below.

Essentially I'm aiming for a similar layout to the GMail interface.

On a side note, lbl_date and lbl_mileage need to take priority and should never be truncated or hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_details"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Details"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_mileage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Preview in Android Studio

[image: Preview in Android Studio]

View in Emulator / Device
[image: View in Emulator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use the **LinearLayout** and attribute **layout_weight**, if **orientation** is **horizontal**, the **layout_width** should set to 0dp, if **orientation** is **vertical** the **layout_height** should set to 0dp.

try to change

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

the code below  will keep your dateText on the RightSide.

use  width=wrapContent and weight=0(default) to keep you conponent not to be  truncated or streched by Weight Function.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_date"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
```